# FirebaseFirestore.instance.data.documents - documents isn't defined for the type Future<Object?>

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

It's just like in the question
[The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Object' - Flutter Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71278417/16007840)
but the answer doesn't work for me and I couldn't comment that because I'm short on reputation.

```
: Error: The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the class 
'Object?'.
lib/…/chat/messages.dart:35
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or 
defining a getter or field named 'documents'.
        final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.documents;
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
lib/…/chat/messages.dart:44
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or 
defining a getter or field named 'uid'.
            chatDocs[index]['userId'] == futureSnapshot.data.uid,
                                                             ^^^
: Error: The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Object?>?'.
lib/…/chat/messages.dart:14
- 'User' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' 
('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth- 
3.3.19/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart:1
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
                                ^
```

Comment: Do you have exactly the same issue as the one stated in the stackoverflow question you mentioned above?

Comment: instead of "isn't defined for the type 'Object'" it's "isn't defined for the type 'Future<Object?>" for me :( thanks for checking out

Comment: please could you screenshot your code and display it here so that we can have a better idea of what is going on

Comment: okayyy wait a sec

Comment: okay seen, and what is the exact error returned to you?

Comment: yeah added that too

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: oh sorry @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: The property is nowadays called `docs` rather than `documents`. See https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html